# Finding the limit of this sequence using the squeeze theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The n-th term is given by $$a_{n}:=\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-2}}+...+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-n-2}}$$
then using the squeeze theorem I find that:
$$\frac{(n+1)n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-n-2}}\leq \frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-2}}+...+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-n-2}}\leq\frac{(n+1)n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}$$
for every $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\left\{1\right\}$,
and since the limits of both the left hand side and right hand side sequence are equal to one, I find that $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-2}}+...+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-n-2}}=1$$
The next part of the problem is to find $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }(a_{n})^{2}$, which is the same as $(\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n})^{2}$, and thus has the same solution, namely 1. Is this correct?
The next task is to find $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }(a_{n})^{n}$, which, by the same logic as stated above, equals one, too. The problem is that this answer isn't given in the answer sheet. One of the possible solutions to this is $e^{2}$, which according to my wolfram calculus app is correct. But how to get there?

Comment: To illustrate the issue in a form you may be familiar with, if $a_n=1+\frac1n$ then the limit of $a_n$ is $1$ but the limit of $a_n^{n}$ is $e^1$.  I suspect you were asked for $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }(a_{n}^{n})$ rather than $(\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n})^{n}$, which makes no sense

Comment: Yeah, now I see. I will edit the question, but one more thing, isn't that just the same thing when the sequence converges to one?

Comment: No it is not the same, as my example shows

Comment: Alright, now I see why. But, is my first assumption correct, for the power of two? And what steps do you recommend for solving it with the power of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }(a_{n})^{n}=\lim \left ( \frac{n^{2}}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}} +\frac{2n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}\right )^{n}=\lim \left ( 1+ \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}{2n}}\right )^{\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}{2n}\cdot \frac{2n^{2}}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}}=e^{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are $n+2$ terms in the definition of $a_n$, and the terms in the sum are increasing,  so you should have

$$\frac{(n+2)n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}\leq a_n \leq \frac{(n+2)n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-n-2}}$$

but your squeeze argument would still work to say $a_n \to 1$.  Your argument would also work for $a_n^2 \to 1$, but it would not work $a_n^n$.

Personally I would suggest trying for a series expansion of $\frac{(n+2)n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-n-2}}$ and $\frac{(n+2)n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{6}-1}}$.  If you find it difficult directly, then you could look at the series expansion of their cubes by polynomial division, which both start $1+6n^{-1}+12n^{-2}+8n^{-3}+\cdots$, so $\lim a_n^{3n} = \lim \left(1+\frac6n\right)^n=e^6$ and taking cube roots will give you $\lim a_n^{n}$.

Comment: I would say that there are n+1 terms. How did you get that number anyway?

Comment: Suppose $n=2$.  Then $n^6-1=63$ and $n^6-n-2=60$ and you have $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{63}}+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{62}}+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{61}}+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{60}}$, which is the sum of $4$ (i.e. $n+2$) terms

Comment: Oh, sorry that I reply so late, but I had already figured it out on my own, and even found an easier way to calculate this limit. Do you wanna see?

Comment: You can if you wish edit your question or post your own answer.

Comment: There, I added an answer.